# How to create PDF using WebAPI with angular js

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, webapi

### My API Method:

```
var stream = PdfUtility.PdfGenaration.GenaratePdfWithStream(body);
above will return bytes.
 HttpResponseMessage result1 = new HttpResponseMessage();
 result1.Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream);
 result1.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
 result1.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "TEST";
 result1.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

 return result1;
```

---

### Any Angular Code

```
 var file = new Blob([data], { type: "application/pdf" });
            saveAs(file, "test.pdf");
```

I am getting empty PDF. Any one help in this?